# How to "randomize" animation in main game loop

Tags: android, animation, random, game-loop

I have an animation(see video link below) that is apart of an app I'm working on. I basically have fish swimming across the screen. Currently I have an array of about 20 fish each initially positioned one behind the other, and then "swim" across the screen in order. My problem is, this is not the behavior I want. This is just a temporary workaround. What I need to happen instead is that after each fish has reached a certain threshold(let's say less than the last 1/5 of the canvas width), another fish from the array is chosen at random, positioned, and then swims across.

This should repeat for the entire life of the activity. I tried generating a random number once each fish reaches that point, then using it to position the fish at that index and then floating it across but an obvious issue with that is if the random number that is chosen corresponds to the index of a fish that is ALREADY on the canvas..it will disappear(so that it can be repositioned again, etc). Aside from that issue, from my understanding of game dev. so far(I'm still very much a beginner)..random number generation inside the main game loop should be avoided at all costs. But I'm just not sure of any other way to go about this. Hoping to get some insight on an approach from more experienced devs. Thanks guys. Here's a link to the YouTube video I posted for this question

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM6t6f9TaUQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player

TL;DR - I want a bunch of fish to swim across the scream in random order, and have this process repeat until the user exits the activity/app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's ok if the spacing between the fishes remains constant for the life of the app, simply generate the randomish inter-fish offsets at application startup. 1st first swims in... when it reaches random offset #1, fish #2 enters. When fish #2 reaches random offset #2, fish #3 enters, and so on. When a fish leaves the other side of the screen, it goes back in the queue and waits to enter.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing it every frame of a game loop, so any performance would be insignificant.

As for the way to do it:
I would say, make a `List<Integer>` and populate it with the indexes of the fish you have.

When a fish is placed on the screen, `remove` it from the list.

When a new fish is to be chosen, choose at random from 0 to list length.

When a new fish swims off the screen, `add` it back on to the list.

Comment: Where exactly would I generate the random int? I'm checking the x position of each fish in my game loop..and once each has passed a certain point I'm trying to choose at random, bit you can clearly see the problem with that

Comment: I don't really see a problem with it? Once a fish passes a certain x value, call a `SpawnFish` function, which does the logic above. That would keep a constant amount of fish. If you wanted it to look more natural, you could spawn fish at random intervals instead and only remove them when they pass some x-value.

Comment: Right, I see what you're saying. That's kind of how I have it laid out here logically as well. But let's say that my spawnFish() is responsible for picking a random index from a List of indexes when Fish.x is say less than half the canvas width..I get odd behavior in that each fish changes color rapidly. I know it's because of the random num. generation inside the loop but I've no idea how to get around this

Comment: Basically, where am I supposed to be "choose at random from 0 to list length" since it cannot be in my onDraw()?

Comment: It would be in a function called within the draw call, but only called every once in a while, when a fish reaches a certain x point.. you'd have an if there to spawn a new random fish, and remove the current one.. this would only be called once per 1000 frames or however many it takes for a fish to reach the other side.. Also even if it did generate many random numbers in each frame, it would be a very, very small (basically insignificant) performance impact.